# Rotations unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script which moves the player by using axes and I want to not only move the player but to also rotate the player in the direction of axes.

Here is my code which I use for player movement. Does anyone know how can I make it?

```cs
using UnityEngine;
public class moving : MonoBehaviour {
  public float moveSpeed = 5f;
  private Rigidbody r;

  public GameObject camera;

  public string checks1;

  public float Force = 5f;

  private void Start() {
    r = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  }
  void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
      checks1 = "Y";
    }
  }
  private void FixedUpdate() {
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    r.velocity = new Vector3(h * moveSpeed, r.velocity.y, v * moveSpeed);
    if (checks1 == "Y") {
      r.velocity = new Vector3(r.velocity.x, Force, r.velocity.y);
      checks1 = "s";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is a 2D game, and you want your object to point in the movement directionm you should be able to do something like

```
if(r.velocity.magnitude > 0){
    r.rotation = Quaternion.LookAt(r.velocity, Vector3.up);
}
```

The `LookAt`-method should produce a rotation that aligns the Z-axis with the velocity of your object. This assumes the velocity is never directly up/down, if that is possible you either need to add a check, or use another "up" direction that is guaranteed to not be parallel with the velocity.